# Could not find any matches for com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:0.63.+ as no versions of com.facebook.react:hermes-engine are available

Tags: react-native

At first, I posted a question on the react-native gihub because of 'React Native version mismatch.'
my ask => (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37989#issue-1766852723)

Then I received a reply that there was a problem with 0.71.0-rc.0.
(https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37989#issuecomment-1600801392)

My reaction native version is 0.63.4, so I upgraded to 0.63.5 as instructed in the official fix document.

But this time, this error is happening. Please help me.

1.this code is running `./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies --no-build-cache` on vscode

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.esolve dependencies of :app:debugRuntimeClasspath > maven-metadata.xml

* What went wrong:1m 30s]
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalReleaseStaging'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:0.63.+ as no versions of com.facebook.react:hermes-engine are available.
     Required by:path
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 38s
```

2. this code is running on Android Studio

```
Could not find any version that matches com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:0.63.+.
Versions that do not match: 0.71.0-rc.0
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/C:/Users/weits/.m2/repository/com/facebook/react/hermes-engine/
  - file:/D:/Android/funglkids_app_/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/hermes-engine/maven-metadata.xml
  - file:/D:/Android/funglkids_app_/node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven/com/facebook/react/hermes-engine/maven-metadata.xml
  - file:/D:/Android/funglkids_app_/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/facebook/react/hermes-engine/maven-metadata.xml
  - https://devrepo.kakao.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/facebook/react/hermes-engine/maven-metadata.xml
  - http://devrepo.kakao.com:8088/nexus/content/groups/public/com/facebook/react/hermes-engine/maven-metadata.xml
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/react/hermes-engine/maven-metadata.xml
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/hermes-engine/maven-metadata.xml
  - https://www.jitpack.io/com/facebook/react/hermes-engine/maven-metadata.xml
Required by:
    project :app
Search in build.gradle files
```

3.`android/build.gradle` code

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        kotlinVersion = '1.5.31'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1')
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
        }
        maven { url 'https://devrepo.kakao.com/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
        maven { url 'http://devrepo.kakao.com:8088/nexus/content/groups/public/' }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

4.`android/app/build.gradle` code

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,
    deleteDebugFilesForVariant: { true }
]

def useIntlJsc = false

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", true);

android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/libfbjni.so'
        pickFirst '**/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/libgnustl_shared.so'
        //pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libreanimated.so'
    }   

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion '23.1.7779620'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "...."
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 11
        versionName "2.3"
//        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_DEBUG
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_PRODUCTION
        }
        releaseStaging {
            initWith release
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_STAGING
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {    
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.+"  // From node_modules

    if (useIntlJsc) {
        implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
    } else {
        implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
    }

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") {
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
        //def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        //debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        //releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        //releaseStagingImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    implementation project(':@react-native-voice_voice')

    addUnimodulesDependencies()
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
```

My reaction native version is 0.63.4, so I upgraded to 0.63.5 as instructed in the official fix document.

Alternatively, I changed from "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" in the android/app/build.gradle to "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.+".

Answer (score 0):

from what I could understand from details mentioned in this doc is
https://reactnative.dev/architecture/bundled-hermes#android-users

Prior to React Native 0.69, users will be consuming hermes-debug.aar and hermes-release.aar from the hermes-engine NPM package.
I think you should try changing the hermes implementation
to

```
    if (enableHermes) {
       def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
       debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
       releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

or you could try updating your react native version to newer versions
you could use this as a helping tool
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

I hope, I help I'm not exactly sure of the answer myself so dropping above links and references for help